I'm trying to create my own DropDownSearch widget in flutter but cannot set width for the CompositedTransformFollower
// thêm mới drop tự làm
class MyDropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<DanhMucDoiTuongModel> list;
  final String label;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final String? initValue;
  final Function(String) callback;
  bool? searchName = true;
  double? heightDrop;
  MyDropDown(
      {super.key,
      required this.list,
      required this.label,
      required this.controller,
      required this.initValue,
      required this.callback,
      this.searchName,
      this.heightDrop});

  @override
  State<MyDropDown> createState() => _MyDropDownState();
}

class _MyDropDownState extends State<MyDropDown> {
  List<DanhMucDoiTuongModel> searchList = [];
  final LayerLink _layerLink = LayerLink();
  double? _buttonWidth;
  var overlayController = OverlayPortalController();
  var tempLabel = ""; // tên hiển thị khi chọn 1 item

  @override
  void initState() {
    searchList = widget.list;
    if (widget.initValue == null) {
      tempLabel = widget.label;
    } else {
      tempLabel = widget.list
          .firstWhere((element) => element.ID == widget.initValue)
          .Ten;
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CompositedTransformTarget(
      link: _layerLink,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          toggleDrop();
        },
        child: OverlayPortal(
            controller: overlayController,
            overlayChildBuilder: (context) {
              log(_buttonWidth.toString());
              return CompositedTransformFollower(
                link: _layerLink,
                targetAnchor: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                child: LimitedBox(
                  maxWidth: _buttonWidth!,
                  maxHeight: widget.heightDrop ?? 200,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: 8,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 7),
                              child: SizedBox(
                                height: 40,
                                child: TextField(
                                  onChanged: (text) {
                                    if (text.isNotEmpty) {
                                      if (widget.searchName!) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          searchList = widget.list
                                              .where((e) => e.Ten.toUpperCase()
                                                  .contains(text.toUpperCase()))
                                              .toList();
                                        });
                                      } else {
                                        setState(() {
                                          searchList = widget.list
                                              .where((e) => e.Ma.toUpperCase()
                                                  .contains(text.toUpperCase()))
                                              .toList();
                                        });
                                      }
                                    } else {
                                      setState(() {
                                        searchList = widget.list;
                                      });
                                    }
                                  },
                                  controller: widget.controller,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: "Tìm ...",
                                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      horizontal: 10,
                                      vertical: 8,
                                    ),
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            LimitedBox(
                              maxHeight: widget.heightDrop == null
                                  ? 150
                                  : (widget.heightDrop! - 50),
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  itemCount: searchList.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    var curItem = searchList[index];
                                    return InkWell(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        setState(() {
                                          widget.callback(curItem.ID);
                                          tempLabel = curItem.Ten;
                                          searchList = widget.list;
                                          toggleDrop();
                                          // _isOpen = false;
                                          // hideOverlay();
                                        });
                                      },
                                      child: MyItemDrop(curItem: curItem),
                                    );
                                  }),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: MyButtonDrop(label: tempLabel, onTap: toggleDrop)),
      ),
    );
  }

  toggleDrop() {
    _buttonWidth = context.size?.width;
    overlayController.toggle();
  }
}

class MyButtonDrop extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final Function() onTap;
  const MyButtonDrop({super.key, required this.label, required this.onTap});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
        height: 50,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        child: Row(
          children: [Text(label), const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down)],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyItemDrop extends StatelessWidget {
  final DanhMucDoiTuongModel curItem;
  const MyItemDrop({super.key, required this.curItem});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 40,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 10),
          child: Text(curItem.Ten),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I look at this post to do it https://medium.com/snapp-x/creating-custom-dropdowns-with-overlayportal-in-flutter-4f09b217cfce
Still dont know why it not receive my value pass to? How can I do this ?
Already take button in overlay and I call this widget in a AlertDialog
Try search on youtube but nothing work for me

LimitedBox limits its size only when it's unconstrained. You need to wrap your CompositedTransformFollower with UnconstrainedBox.

thank you, this work it take me a lot of time !!!
